# Stars and pins are retained when chat messages are moved!

Tags: bug, chat, chat-stars, chat-pins

In the chat system, stars and pins are retained when moved to another room. This is probably a bug. Here a picture:

[image]

When a room owner pins a message, they can move it to another room, and they cannot unpin it. However when a starred message is moved to another room, the user can unstar it in the room it was moved to.

Conversation source: https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/2412448#2412448

<sub>`*`[The zalgo posted by Shadow Wizard](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/2413044#2413044) is irrelevant and does not have to do with this bug report.

Many thanks to [InfiniteRecursion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/245167/infinite-recursion)<sub>[[chat user]](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/users/245167/infinite-recursion).</sub></sub>

Comment: This bug is still very much real. Stars/pins shouldn't even be movable between rooms.

Comment: This is really a problem, because anybody with room creation privileges (100 network-wide reputation) can pin a message in a room by creating a second room, pinning it there, and moving it to the first room. Users can easy abuse this to pin anything in any public room, totally bypassing the room owners.

Comment: As of [2 hours ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/347089/bug-allows-anyone-to-pin-any-message-in-any-room) this is apparently still an issue.

Comment: @Rubiksmoose sure, chat is abandoned since SE moved internally to Slack.

Comment: @ShadowKeepsSocialDistance: Indeed. I just felt like adding a bit of narrative to the comment instead of dropping the bare link.

Comment: @Rubik sure, all good, being frustrated together helps a bit. ;)