# Bug allows anyone to pin any message in any room!

Tags: bug, chat, security, chat-stars

I found a small bug that allows any user to pin a message even if they are not a Room Owner. If a message is pinned and then moved, it remains pinned in the room it is moved to even if the user who moved it isn't a Room owner in the new room.

**To reproduce**

1. Go to chat
2. Create a room
3. Post a message and pin it
4. Move the message to any room
5. See the message pinned in the new room

**In action**

I am not a room owner in the [Android room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15/android). However, I posted a message in my [testing room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193540/test-my-bot), pinned it, and then moved it to the android room. It is now pinned there.

https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/49226502#49226502

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/messages/49226502/history

Comment: @Randal'Thor Yes and no. The question there doesn't describe this consequence of the ability to move pinned and stared messages. The comment under that question, however, does. Not sure if this should be closed for that.

Comment: Additionally there's no answers there.

Comment: That's true, there aren't any answers there, but that's because it hasn't been fixed yet. When it *is* fixed, a developer will post an answer confirming that it was addressed. Given that your report is much more modern (and has repro steps!) we can use it as a great pointer to that duplicate.

Comment: @Spevacus  "when", more like "if" considering SO seems to have given up on chat. But I agree, it's fine this was closed as sup.